# Why do AndroidManifest.xml files have redundant android:label attributes?

Tags: android, android-manifest

[The DevGuide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#label) on the application element's `android:label`:

> A user-readable label for the application as a whole, and a default label for each of the application's components.

Yet, there's a world of example manifests that have the form

```
<application ... android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity ... android:label="@string/app_name"> ... </activity>
    <activity ... android:label="@string/app_name"> ... </activity>
    ...
</application>
```

Every single Android book I have does this, including the Commonsware books.  A glance through the SDK examples shows that ContactManager does this, but not Snake or Lunar Lander.

*Is there some historical reason for the attribute to be duplicated like this?*  Or is it, like Eclipse's stub comments that people leave in post-stub code (and book examples, in one case), or like the duplicate labels in my own imitative manifests, just something that people don't think about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No AndroidManifest.xml of the API *2* (Android 1.1) SDK samples has this redundancy.  I conclude that it was never necessary, and that it's a (harmless) example of cargo-cult programming.

Answer (score 0):

i think the `activity` tag with the attribute `android:label` is not necessary, except you want make the activity the title different with the application label, you can use your own label. the default should be as same as the application label.

Answer (score 0):

A single App can have more than on icon in the Android Launcher as each icon can map to a single activity. A activity with below intent filter will be show as a standalone icon in launcher

```
<intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

The value of android:label will be shown as the name under that icon in lancher

Comment: This answers the question "what is android:label for?", which I didn't ask.